# calc() not working correctly with complex calculations

Tags: css, responsive-design

I know that this topic was posted many times but I can't find answer for my question about `calc()` function.
I know the problem with space between `+` and `-` but this time the problem is not associated with this.

I can't correctly display 3 images in a row using
`width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);`

The last image should be placed in the same row but it's moved down. It has `margin-right: 0` so expression `calc((100% - 20px) / 3)` should keeping those three `img` in a one row next to each other.

Complete code

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; background: red;}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
  
  &.last { margin-right: 0; }
}
```

```html
<!-- images should be displayed
      - in a row
      - with margin right 20px except last
------------------------------------------->

<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3); should be used instead of 20px. since 1st and second element margin 20px+20px; Ensure margin-right is applied to the last element

Comment: The `calc` is valid and you can check this yourself: `CSS.supports("width", "calc((100% - 20px) / 3)")` returns `true`, so of course it has nothing to do with missing spaces around operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `40px` instead of `20px`.

You have 3 images with `margin-right: 20px` each except the last one. So it will be **(3 * 20) - 20 = 40**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
}
img.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- images should be displayed
      - in a row
      - with margin right 20px except last
------------------------------------------->

<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: It would be worth explaining that the `- 40px` is the first two items right margins, just giving out working code helps, but he won't learn what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following solution:

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  background: red;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: calc((100% - (20px * 2)) / 3);
}
.row3 img {
  width: calc((100% - (20px * 2)) / 3);
}
.row5 img {
  width: calc((100% - (20px * 4)) / 5);
}
img.last {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- example original -->
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">

<!-- example 3 images -->
<div class="row3">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg"> 
</div>

<!-- example 5 images -->
<div class="row5">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg"> 
</div>
```

**The formula to calculate the image width of every image in container:**

```
calc(([width-of-container] - ([margin-lr-images] * [count-images - 1])) / [count-images])
```

Comment: He needs that the last one does not have `margin-right`.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are 2 images with `margin-right: 20px`, the width of the line should be `100% - 40px` then divided by 3 (20px x 2).

Please see below revised code - I've also corrected the `.last` class so it renders with normal CSS.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; background: red;}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
}
img.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<!-- images should be displayed
      - in a row
      - with margin right 20px except last
------------------------------------------->

<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
<img class="last" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
```